# Can’t loop through a nested list

Tags: python

I can’t seem to iterate through a nested loop.

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
for i in lst:
    print(lst.index(i))
```

The result I get is:

```
0
0
0
```

I expected to see:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: ``index(i)`` will return the first index of `i`.You should use `for i in range(len(lst)):print(i)`;

Comment: `.index()` *return the index of the first occurrence*. You can use `enumerate` or `range(len(...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
for i,val in enumerate(lst):
    print((i))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because you have similar elements in the list 'lst'. Also when you do lst.index(element), it gives you the index of the first such element found in 'lst'. As all your elements are same, you are getting 0,0,0. For getting index of elements you should loop like:

```
for index,element in enumerate(lst):
         print(index)
         print(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach works only when all sublists are different:

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
for i in lst:
    print(lst.index(i))
```

Only in this case you get the expected values 0, 1, 2.